# Tensorflow Speech Recognition

Tags: tensorflow, tflearn

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tflearn

import speech_data

learning_rate = 0.0001
training_iters = 3000  # steps
batch_size = 64

width = 20  # mfcc features
height = 80  # (max) length of utterance
classes = 10  # digits

batch = word_batch = speech_data.mfcc_batch_generator(batch_size)

# Network building
net = tflearn.input_data([None, width, height])
net = tflearn.lstm(net, 128*4, dropout=0.5)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, classes, activation='softmax')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=learning_rate, loss='categorical_crossentropy')
model = tflearn.DNN(net, tensorboard_verbose=0)

## add this "fix" for tensorflow version errors
for x in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES): tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES, x )

# Training

while --training_iters > 0:
    trainX, trainY = next(batch)
    testX, testY = next(batch)  # todo: proper ;)
    model.fit(trainX, trainY, n_epoch=10, validation_set=(testX, testY), show_metric=True, batch_size=batch_size)

model.save("tflearn.lstm.model")
_y = model.predict(next(batch)[0])  # << add your own voice here
print (_y)
```

Problem 1: If i run this code inside the loop (while --training_iters > 0:) it never stops even after 3000 steps it keeps on going.. Why is this so..

My question is how do u get the output i.e how do i start the prediction .. when i run this code i get the following [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UneyK.png) (After commenting the loop) .. what does that output mean.. and how do i predict the numbers.?

Comment: The fit function already does the looping over data for you, thats why there is a param `n_epoch`. The outputs are the prediction class probabilities. And argmax() on those will give you the predicted class label.

Comment: can u just show how to do the argmax() ... and so should i increase the number of epochs and remove the loop?

Answer (score 0):

remove while loop

while --training_iters > 0

and increase number of epoch

Comment: Please read this [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to improve your answer.